# Generate NGC for custom VHDL module in IPCore Xilinx

Tags: hardware, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am trying to implement a custom IPCore for the Zedboard. In my User_Logic I am including a component (My_Module) from the VHDL module (My_Module.vhd) which I wrote as part of the ISE project. But when I come to generate the bitstream for my design in PlanAhead it asks for the My_Module.ngc as if it is treating it as a blackbox. I though the NGC was only required when using CoreGen IPCores, but it seems it also wants it for any VHDL module included as I guess this is a 'black box'.

The issue is how do I create a NGC file from the VHDL for this module, which is part of an ISE project. As I can't find any function in ISE that allows you to just generate the netlist for one VHDL module. Or can I export this module out into a separate ISE project and then synthesise it to get the .ngc?

Many thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is to generate the NGC files by making the modules you want "the top module" you can then run the synthesis to generate the individual NGC. Then proceed as normal when adding IP to a PCore. So adding these NGC files to the netlist folder and modifying the BBD file and all that!

As a note for completion to get the module working you need to set the synthesis setting "Xilinx Specefic" -> and disable "add io buffers"

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've typed the module name in exactly the same way both in your module `.vhd` file, and in the file using the module as a component?

Under normal circumstances, if your project includes the module as a `.vhd` file, it'll just be synthesized along with the rest of your sources - I did a quick test and renamed a component in one of my own projects, and got a complaint about a possibly missing .ngc file (this was in ISE, and not in PlanAhead though).

Comment: Yes I am sure, In ISE and XPS, the project synthesises and implementation runs fine. Its only in PlanAhead this problem occurs, which puzzles me!

Comment: The other puzzling thing is that when generating the netlist in XPS it would usually throw this error before I even got the PlanAhead synthesis stage if it required the ngc file for the build. But here it runs in XPS but not PlanAhead.

Comment: Sounds strange - I haven't really used PlanAhead for managing projects, so can't help much with that. You should probably add to your question that the problem is specific to PlanAhead, and that everything is fine in ISE though. And maybe also a few snippets of code (for instance declarations of you module / component / etc).

Comment: Very strange but I found a work around by generating the NGC files for each module. Though I'm sure there must be a config somewhere so I don't have to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Are you including My_Module.vhd as a source file in your ISE Project?  If you are, check to see that the ISE project doesn't have a yellow question mark next to the My_Module component.  If it does, then it needs more information about that component.  You should see a little icon with the letters VHD in it in your ISE Implementation Hierarchy View.

Comment: Nope all fine, the My_Module.vhd source was created in the usual way of creating a new VHDL module so there are no problems with linking.

Comment: Did you remember to include a component definition prior to your architecture in the file that instantiates the My_Module?  I think you would have had a compile error if you didn't, but just thought I would ask.